# Регулярное выражение " Только буквы, цифры, пробел и дробь " для проверки формы ввода на сайт

Tags: javascript, html, css, регулярные-выражения

Нужно Добавить адрес в личный кабинет пользователя.

```
             <div class="popup-add_info">
                <div class="user_info">
                    <p>Улица</p>
                    <div class="input_wrapp">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="user_info">
                    <p>Дом</p>
                    <div class="input_wrapp">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="user_info">
                    <p>Корпус</p>
                    <div class="input_wrapp">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="user_info">
                    <p>Квартира</p>
                    <div class="input_wrapp">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn_wrapp_2">
                <div class="col">
                    <a href="#" class="green_pill_2 save">Сохранить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <a href="#" class="red_pill cansel">Отмена</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Он должен будет выглядеть к примеру вот так

> ул. Куйбышева 111 кв. 93

То есть нужно получить правильно название улицы, дом, корпус (если он есть) и квартиру.
Мне нужно регулярное выражение которое проверит что строка содержит только 
буквы, цифры, пробел и дробь. А также если в поле только пробел то оно считается не заполненным.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
^[а-я][А-Я][0-9][.][ ]$
```

Данное регулярное выражение разрешает наличие всех букв русского алфавита, а также цифр,точек и пробелов.
Думаю, это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Вы сами пробовали свой regex? Он пропустит только что-то типа ```вЩ7. ```.

Answer (score 0):

Валидация адреса при помощи регулярных выражений это не самая лучшая идея, так как адрес это не всегда улица, дом, квартира. Про это есть очень хорошая [статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/company/hflabs/blog/260601/).

Но если вас интересует только набор символов без структуры, то вот это должно подойти:

```
^(?!\s*$)[-\/'"№., 0-9а-яА-Я]+$
```

Я дополнительно добавил запятую, кавычки и знак номера. Имейте в виду, что это выражение разрешает пробелы в начале и конце строки.